# public header files in iOS static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have developed static library for my applications. It generates .framework, .bundle, .a files.

I want to enhance the use of library. Currently my framework has 4-5 files as public scope to application. Only those headers are visible to application (Interface). Is there any way to create common header file at build time of framework, which will contain/ imports of all public files from my source code(frame work code.)

e.g. once I build framework code, it will generate .framework which will create/have common.h header file consisting all imports of public files.

By doing this, application needs to import only common.h. I know we can do this manually also. But is there any scope to do this by script at build time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using script I got success!

Here are the steps:
1. In build script where we create fat binary, we need to find out all .h headers. We need to take path in variable.
2. Loop and collect all public variable
3. Create and locate common.h (This will be path of header folder in .framework)
4. Put all files common.h